# Image overlay and responsive design

Tags: css, responsive-design, overlay

I have to overlay two images to obtain the fade effect on the page scroll, and this not a problem, it works well. The problem is that if I don't set a height to the `.square-banner` class, the banners are overlapped by the following ones (second picture). Because the website is responsive I need to eliminate the height to the .square-banner class and I don't have found a solution for this.

```
<div id="banner-1-1" class="square-banner">
    <img class="img-bottom" id="img-bottom-1" src="images/prodigio-wording.jpg">
    <img class="img-top" id="img-top-1" src="images/prodigio.jpg">
</div>

.square-banner {
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  height: 430px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.img-bottom, .img-top {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
display:block;
float:left; 
}

.square-banner img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Because of the image `position:absolute` (to have them overlay), the `.square-banner` doesn't occupy space in height. This is the real problem I have to solve.

Comment: Your .square-banner is floated left.  Did you clear the floats after?

Comment: All the three banners have the same class square-banner then all are floated left. What do you mean with "clear the floats after" ?

Comment: Sorry I forget to say that the images are positioned as absolute to make them overlay. For this reason the container doesn't have height ... this is the real proble i think                                                                  .square-banner img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

Comment: Nothing in the code you posted shows that it was positioned using absolute.  You should post more code so it can be reviewed.
But when you float elements, it takes them out of the normal flow so you need to clear. GIve this a read: https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/
And to your comment, if you position absolutely and the parent has no height, that may be the root of your layout issue.

Comment: If you want to overlay them _and_ push them, why don't you only make **one** image `absolute` and the other `relative`? If they are the only items in the wrapping container this will make them overlap _and_ give the box a height. This works as long as both images have the same size. Just make sure the container has a `position: relative` set as well.

Comment: Thanks "somethinghere", your suggestion solved my problem !

Comment: @Luca I just posted an answer with that in it, actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code snippet shows how you can overlay two images of the same size by simply making *one* absolute. The other one will allow you box to have a height automatically, no floating required. Now you can move around the `#container` and reshape it any way you want.

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');
container.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  container.className = container.className === 'other' ? '' : 'other';
});
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
}
#container img {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}
#container img:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}
#container.other img {
  opacity: 0;
}
#container.other img:first-child {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/dd0300" />
</div>
```

*Click on the snippet to switch the visual layer from red to gray.*

Comment: Thanks again ... so obvious but I didn't think about this :-)